# r assign nearest available value to NA

Tags: r, na, nearest-neighbor

instead a for loop, is there a short and efficient way to assign nearest available value to NA in that column in a dataframe? E.g, there's a dataframe DF

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y1 = c(0, 10, NA,5, 20,30,7,8,9,11), y2 = c(NA, 0, NA,5, 20,30,7,8,NA,NA), z = c(95,94,90:87,88,89,90,91))

    x y1 y2  z
1   1  0 NA 95
2   2 10  0 94
3   3 NA NA 90
4   4  5  5 89
5   5 20 20 88
6   6 30 30 87
7   7  7  7 88
8   8  8  8 89
9   9  9 NA 90
10 10 11 NA 91
```

And the final DF should be

```
    x y1 y2  z
1   1  0  0 95
2   2 10  0 94
3   3 10  0 90
4   4  5  5 89
5   5 20 20 88
6   6 30 30 87
7   7  7  7 88
8   8  8  8 89
9   9  9  8 90
10 10 11  8 91
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(na.locf(DF), fromLast = TRUE)
```

Comment: Works as MAGIC! Thanks a lot!